# Help with arrow notation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

My apologies if this question is too dumb but I am not too familiar with the $\leadsto$ notation. I came across with this remark:[image]

Can someone please tell me the meaning of $\leadsto$ in this case???

Thanks in advance

Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is defined for you in the final equation.

It means the matrix where $0$'s are appended at the bottom.

This is not a standard notation and it is not clear if we always append a single row of $0$'s or could it be multiple rows of zeros.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this is not really standard notation.

Comment: yes, in fact, it is not clear that whether  it is always a single row of $0$'s or could be be multiple rows of zeros.